# Global Keyboard hook to stop script

Tags: vbscript

I've created a login script in VBScript but i would like to add a way to stop if a key is being pressed.

The script currently loads our citrix desktop and sets a few mapped drives but i'd like to add a if statement to say for example:

```
If keyPressed(F10) not true Then
```

Unfortunately this is beyond my means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK VBScript doesn't support asynchronous polling for a key-press. There may be different means to the same end, though.

For one thing, you could make the script a startup script (i.e. a shortcut in a startup folder). That way your users could skip over it by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> at logon (until the desktop icons appear). The downside of this approach is that it doesn't skip selectiveley. Either all startup shortcuts are executed, or none.

Another (perhaps more suitable) way might be the [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f) method.

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

loadCitrix = sh.Popup("Load Citrix Desktop?", 10, , vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

Select Case loadCitrix
  Case -1, vbYes : ...
  Case vbNo      : ...
End Select
```

This will display a popup message for 10 seconds and then proceed with either the value of the pressed button or the default (`-1` means "no button was pressed").